CORS Error in Laravel Vapor despite configuring cors.php properly
I am facing a persistent CORS error in my Laravel Vapor project, even though I have configured the cors.php file correctly. Here are the details:
Project Setup:
Backend: Laravel (deployed on Vapor)
Frontend: Vue.js (deployed on a different domain)
Issue:
When making API calls from the frontend to the backend, I encounter the following CORS error:
Access to fetch at 'backend_domain_url' from origin 'frontend_domain_url' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
CORS Configuration:
In the backend (cors.php), I have configured CORS as follows:
'paths' => ['api/*'],
'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins' => ['frontend_domain_url'],
'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
'exposed_headers' => [],
'max_age' => 0,
'supports_credentials' => false,

Despite this, the CORS policy continues to block requests, and the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is not present in the response.
Steps I've Tried:
Checked that the frontend domain is correctly listed in allowed_origins.
Verified that requests are sent with the correct origin headers.
Tried adjusting the CORS headers, but no success so far.
What could be causing the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to be missing, and how can I resolve this issue in a Laravel Vapor project? Is there anything specific to Vapor’s environment that might affect CORS behavior?

A few questions: Are your api routes set in routes/api.php? That would mean that the CORS settings are already configured. Is the frontend loaded over HTTPS, and your API over HTTP? in that case the CORS error would also be triggered.

What is the version of Laravel? What is the middleware namespace "HandleCors" in Kernel?

In my experience, cors errors are rarely cors errors. Something else might be failing in the server. Can you check if there's nothing weird with permissions in the logs folder?  (ls -lah storage/logs)

Yes, the routes are in routes/api.php, and both the backend and frontend domains are on a secure protocol (HTTPS).
I’m using Laravel version 11, which comes with the inbuilt CORS package. I’ve handled the CORS middleware in bootstrap/app.php with the following:
\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,

I will check the logs folder permissions (ls -lah storage/logs) and see if there's anything missing or unusual. Thanks for the suggestion!

Let check your request header, I think you are missing header authority so Laravel can't know where request from so => it will be blocked by CORS
